# iPhone Web Form - Disable Prev/Next | Autofill | Done bar

Tags: iphone, html

Is it possible to disable or suppress the bar that shows up on web forms that has the (Previous|Next) Autofill and Done button on it?

I've seen posts regarding adding or suppressing it in native apps but I'm working on a web app and curious if it's just an attribute to add to the form like how the auto-capitalize and auto-correct on the input fields are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to suppress the the bar.

The bar is not exposed, not even in native apps web using the `UIWebView`.

Comment: Boo, I had guessed that was the answer but didn't definitively see it anywhere.